# Error while installing R-3.4.0, libcurl

Tags: r, curl, libcurl

I am trying to install R-3.4.0 from source but am getting an error about not having libcurl >= 7.22. However, it appears that I do have libcurl 7.47.0. Any help?

```
~/R-3.4.0$ ./configure
...
configure: error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https

~/R-3.4.0$ curl -V
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
```

Comment: What OS/version are you trying to do this on? Where there any other errors or warnings?

Comment: You have the `curl` binary but probably not the header or libraries necessary for compilation.

Comment: Can you try to run `apt-get install libcurl-dev`?

Comment: Thanks @Harald, that worked.

Comment: @MrFlick ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There were no other errors.